# How to find error in this web scraping (bot) code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to build a bot to send requests in linkedin. But after running this code, it works till 42 line, then stop. how I can find out the error? There is a config.txt file containing user and password. For security purpose, I am not giving this file. Can anyone help me in this regard?

```
import os, random, sys, time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?trk=hb_signin')

file = open('config.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
username = lines[0]
passwd = lines[1]

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys(username)

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys(passwd)

elementID.submit()

myID = '/in/kafee-khan-097a5b129/'
fulllink = 'https://www.linkedin.com/' + myID
browser.get(fulllink)

visitedProfiles = []
profileQueued = []

def getNewProfileIDs(soup,profileQueued):
    profilesID = []
    pav = soup.find('div',{'class':'pv-browsemap-section'})
    all_links = pav.findAll('a',{'class':'pv-browsemap-section__member ember-view'})
    for link in all_links:
        userID = link.get('href')
        if((userID not in visitedProfiles) and (userID not in profileQueued)):
            profilesID.append(userID)
    return profilesID
    

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
getNewProfileIDs(soup, profileQueued) 

while profileQueued:
    try:
        visitedID = profileQueued.pop()
        visitedProfiles.append(visitedID)
        fullLink = "hhttps://www.linkedin.com" + visitedID
        browser.get(fullLink)

        browser.find_element_by_class_name('pv-s-profile-actions pv-s-profile-actions--connect ml2 artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view').click()

        browser.find_element_by_class_name('mr1').click()

        message = "Hello, I am Muktadir. I like to connect with you."
        elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('custom-message')
        elementID.send_keys(message)

        browser.find_element_by_class_name('artdeco-modal__dismiss').click()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        try:
            profileQueued.extend(getNewProfileIDs(soup, profileQueued))
        except:
            print('Continue')

    except:
        print('error')
```

Comment: "I also want to know how to debug this code". Please raise one issue only per one SO question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debugging` the practice on software development where you can find out what's happening to you code.
If you're using vs code [here is how you debug.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Vs code is a nice code editor with plenty of plugins that turns it into an [IDE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiN1d6-mtzqAhUTILkGHV1QACMQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codecademy.com%2Farticles%2Fwhat-is-an-ide&usg=AOvVaw3QhCAdDM4gx3zxVYghGOnD)

But there're another options, like [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm)